# XML Flash player

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2

Id like to put a flash image gallery that reads an XML and displays the relevant images on my website, however id like to be able to programatically get at a certain slideshow in my XML using its id. for example,  my XML has x number of slideshows(i've just copied and pasted the slideshows and changed the id). As an example id like to get at slideshow elements with the id 2.
If i was using XPath in XSLT i would do something like "location/image_gallery/slideshow[@id = 2]".

```
<location>
<image_gallary>
    <slideshow id="1" width="230" height="145" speed="2">
       <image url="graphics/chesterfield.jpg" title="Market Walk" href="htle.co.uk/" />
       <image url="graphics/cranley.jpg" title="History" href="http://www.google.co.uk/" /> 
    </slideshow>

    <slideshow id="3" width="230" height="145" speed="4">
       <image url="graphics/chesterfield.jpg" title="rket Walk" href="http://www.google.co.uk/" />
       <image url="graphics/cranley.jpg" title="History" href="http://www.google.co.uk/" />
    </slideshow>

    <slideshow id="2" width="230" height="145" speed="3">
       <image url="graphics/chesterfield.jpg" title="rket Walk" href="http://www.google.co.uk/" />
       <image url="graphics/cranley.jpg" title="History" href="http://www.google.co.uk/" />
    </slideshow>
</image_gallery>
</location>

*note that the id's can be in any order, i can hard code the actionscript to get to a particular slideshow, however id like to be able to programatically use the id and then call it in my xslt. Any help would be appreciated.

Im using actionscript 2.0. Here is what i have

import mx.transitions.Tween;
import mx.transitions.easing.*;

var myShowXML = new XML();
myShowXML.ignoreWhite = true;
myShowXML.load("xml/london_gb.xml");

myShowXML.onLoad = function() {

_root.myWidth = myShowXML.firstChild.childNodes[0].firstChild.attributes.width;
_root.myHeight = myShowXML.firstChild.childNodes[0].firstChild.attributes.height;
_root.mySpeed = myShowXML.firstChild.childNodes[0].firstChild.attributes.speed;

_root.myImages = myShowXML.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.childNodes;
_root.myImagesNo = myImages.length;

trace(myImages.length);

createContainer();
callImages();

};

function createContainer() {

_root.createEmptyMovieClip("myContainer_mc",_root.getNextHighestDepth());

myContainer_mc.lineTo(_root.myWidth,0);
myContainer_mc.lineTo(_root.myWidth,_root.myHeight);
myContainer_mc.lineTo(0,_root.myHeight);
myContainer_mc.lineTo(0,0);

myContainer_mc._x = (Stage.width-myContainer_mc._width)/2;
myContainer_mc._y = (Stage.height-myContainer_mc._height)/2;

};

function callImages() {

_root.myMCL = new MovieClipLoader();
_root.myPreloader = new Object();
_root.myMCL.addListener(_root.myPreloader);

_root.myClips_array = [];

_root.myPreloader.onLoadComplete = function(target) {

_root.myClips_array.push(target);
target._alpha=0;

if (_root.myClips_array.length == _root.myImagesNo) {

moveSlide();
myShowInt = setInterval(moveSlide, (_root.mySpeed*1000)+1000);
}

}

for (i=0; i<_root.myImagesNo; i++) {

temp_url = _root.myImages[i].attributes.url;
temp_mc = myContainer_mc.createEmptyMovieClip(i,    myContainer_mc.getNextHighestDepth());

_root.myMCL.loadClip(temp_url,temp_mc);
}

};

function moveSlide (){

current_mc = _root.myClips_array[_root.target_mc];
new Tween(current_mc, "_alpha", Strong.easeOut, 100, 0, 1, true);

_root.target_mc++;

if (_root.target_mc >= _root.myImagesNo){
_root.target_mc = 0;
}

next_mc = _root.myClips_array[_root.target_mc];
new Tween(next_mc, "_alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 100, 1, true);

};
```

Comment: I didn't get u.. can u explain what you wants to do?

Comment: hey, basically i want to be able to get at the element slideshow dependant on the id, not the way ive written it in the actionscript i.e firstChild.childNodes etc etc etc

Answer (score 0):

_xmlContainer.imageGallary.slideshow.@id[0];

try this one.

Answer (score 0):

add this line

```
next_mc.onRelease = function() {
    getURL(_root.myImages[target_mc].attributes.href,"_blank");
};
```

below this line

```
next_mc = _root.myClips_array[_root.target_mc];
```

Comment: Care to comment your code? Why adding the line will help the OP? How does it works? Commenting will help to get a better answer so others can benefit from it